# Can't define instance method with data variable

Tags: haskell, module

At first, I tried to solve mutual recursive module problem. However, my effort to solve this problem makes the code worse.

## Original problem

I have two module like

```
module W where

import T

data W = W  { wName  :: String
            , queue  :: [T W]}`
```

and

```
module T where

import W

data T = T { tName  :: String
            , tUpdate :: W -> IO W}

class Manage a where
    update :: a -> W -> IO W

instance Manage T where
    update = tUpdate
```

These modules are not able to work, because of mutual recursive modules problem.

So I changed `module T`, according to [this link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Mutually_recursive_modules)

## New solution with data variable

```
module T where

data T w = T { tName  :: String
            , tUpdate :: w -> IO w}

class Manage a where
    update :: a -> w -> IO w

instance Manage (T w) where
    update = tUpdate
```

However, this code makes error like:

```
Couldn't match type ‘w’ with ‘w1’
  ‘w’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at TestModule2.hs:12:10
  ‘w1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for update :: T w -> w1 -> IO w1
       at TestModule2.hs:13:5
Expected type: T w -> w1 -> IO w1
  Actual type: T w -> w -> IO w
Relevant bindings include
  update :: T w -> w1 -> IO w1 (bound at TestModule2.hs:13:5)
In the expression: tUpdate
In an equation for ‘update’: update = tUpdate
```

So, I tried many things to solve this problem like

## Introduce new class like `State w` to represent `data W`

To solve `rigid type variable ...`, I introduced new class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs, Rank2Types #-}
module T where

.....

data T w = T  { tName  :: String
              , tUpdate :: (State w) => w -> IO w}

class Manage a where
    update :: (State w) => a -> (w -> IO w)

instance (State w) => Manage (T w) where
    update :: T w -> w -> IO w
    update = tUpdate
```

But this code also makes error like:

```
Method signature does not match class; it should be
  update :: forall w1. State w1 => T w -> w1 -> IO w1
In the instance declaration for ‘Manage (T w)’
```

I followed this suggestion, but this doesn't work.
Moreover, `w1` and `w` should be same type.

Do I need to define class or class method other way?

## So, What do I need to study and how could I solve this problem?

I tried more things, but I couldn't solve this.
What do I need to study to solve this problem?
And how could I solve this problem?

## Important points:

1. I need to separate this two module.
2. As possible as I can, I do not want to use hs-boot, but more elegant way

Comment: This has nothing to do with modules. The `w` in `update :: a -> w -> IO w` and the `w` in `instance Manage (T w)` are completely unrelated. You probably want something like `class Manage a w | a -> w where update :: a -> w -> IO w` and `instance Manage (T w) w`. Or possibly `class Manage a where update :: a w -> w -> IO w`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew that `w`s are not related, but I had no way.  The first of your answer works. However,the second one makes error like `The first argument of ‘Manage’ should have kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘T w’ has kind ‘*’`. It seems to be better then the first one, but...

Comment: If you use the 2nd suggestion, it will be `instance Manage T`, not `instance Manage (T w)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038) comments, one solution can be :

Module T:

```
module T where

data T w = T { tName   :: String
             , tUpdate :: w -> IO w
             }

class Manage a where
    update :: a w -> w -> IO w

instance Manage T where
    update = tUpdate
```

Module W:

```
module W where

import T

data W = W { wName :: String
           , queue :: [T W]
           }
```

Comment: Thanks zigazou, user2407038 a lot. These answers are very helpful for me.